# How does context switch of slot happens when a sleep is done in the task thread of a flink custom source?

Tags: apache-flink

I have a custom source which generates some events every x mins. I have referred [this](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-end-to-end-tests/flink-cli-test/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/tests/PeriodicStreamingJob.java) file and my code is something like below

```
public class PeriodicSourceGenerator extends RichParallelSourceFunction<GenericMetric> {
    private transient AtomicBoolean isRunning;
    @Override
    public void open(final Configuration c) throws Exception {
        isRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<GenericMetric> ctx) throws Exception {
        while (isRunning.get()) {
            //noinspection BusyWait
            Thread.sleep(300000); // 5 mins
            final long ts = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
            final MetricStore.MetricPoint mp = new MetricStore.MetricPoint(ts, 1, -1);
            synchronized (ctx.getCheckpointLock()) {
                ctx.collectWithTimestamp(new GenericMetric(mk, MetricName.vRNI_internal_droppedTx_flow_absolute_latest_number, mp), ts);
                ctx.collectWithTimestamp(new GenericMetric(mk, MetricName.vRNI_internal_droppedRx_flow_absolute_latest_number, mp), ts);
            }
        }
        logger.info("Job cancelled. Shutting Down Periodic Source Generator");
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        isRunning.set(false);
    }
}
```

I am running multiple pipelines in a single flink job which looks something like below.

[image]

I am running flink with the default operator chaining and slot sharing enabled. All my operators have same parallelism, 30 and I am having 5 task managers so that each task manager has 6 slots.

Can someone let me know how will the sleep in `PeriodicSourceGenerator` pipeline affect the `Collection Source` pipeline? My understanding is that sleep will make the `PeriodicSource` generator pipeline context switched by `Collection Source` pipeline and the entire slot will not get paused for 5 mins. Is my understanding correct?

- Flink Version - 1.13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleeping in one operator won't pause the entire slot -- just the task containing that operator. In this case, sleeping in `PeriodicSourceGenerator` will not affect the `Collection Source` pipeline, since these pipelines aren't connected.

In general, you should avoid sleeping (or blocking) in the main task thread. This has negative consequences, such as blocking checkpointing for the entire job. In this specific case, it's okay to sleep the way you're doing it: i.e., outside of the checkpoint lock.

Comment: Is there a way to have a PeriodicSourceGenerator without doing sleep?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain that more clearly -- what you're doing is fine.

Comment: Thanks David for the confirmation. Just for my understanding what are you referring as the main task thread in flink which will block checkpointing when sleep is used there?

Comment: Any code that is in a user function, such as a flatmap, process function, or a window function.